# Touchpad is now extremely laggy with both Fedora and Debian

Tags: linux, mouse, touchpad, sony-vaio

The touchpad is now extremely laggy, the cursor doesn't move smoothly, with both Fedora and Debian

I have a Sony VAIO. The problem only appeared recently, and what's more I tested with a Debian LiveCD that used to work well, and now the problem with the touchpad cursor appeared, implying that it's not a problem with the updates.

I tested with a USB Mouse but there was no lag with it.